Install fastapi using an older version of pip (9.0.3)
I am in a project that requires an older version of pip (9.0.3) and I wanted to install fastapi on it. When I run:
pip install fastapi

I got:
Collecting fastapi
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fastapi (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for fastapi
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 24.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Would it be possible to workaround this error?

how about you upgrade pip and try again: pip install --upgrade pip

@kakaiikaka The question specifically states that this old version of pip is required by the project.

pip 9.0.3 requires very old Python. What Python do you use? 2.7? 3.5? Even the lowest version of  fastapi 0.1.0 requires Python 3.6+. See the left column at https://pypi.org/project/fastapi/0.1.0/ If you need Fast API you need more modern Python, at least 3.6. pip 9.0.3 works with Python 3.6.
